# NodeJS - Does middleware and next() function exist as a concept within the 'http' module or just in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, http, express, middleware

I'm new to NodeJS and am trying to build out a web server right now using just http.createServer().

I'm trying to understand if the concepts of middleware and the design pattern used in ExpressJS applies outside of ExpressJS.

So specifically I have:

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
```

and handleRequest is just a function:

```
function (request, response) {... response.end()}
```

If I want to process the request, and do things based on the request.url... should I try and do that in a separate function using the concept of middleware like in the ExpressJS world... so it would do something to the request first and then hand it off to handleRequest using `next()`, or do I just do everything with my handleRequest function... but have helper functions within there that I might call out to. For example I could have which is called from within handleRequest:

```
function getUri(request){return url.parse(request.url).pathname}
```

Comment: This is really mostly opinion-based, but there's obviously an upside on having a middleware-style concept to an HTTP server, in that it adds a lot of flexibility and allows for easy reuse due to a common interface. It entirely depends on the requirements and goals of your project if it makes sense to implement something similar.

Comment: So if I wasn't using something like ExpressJS, and just the base 'http' nodejs server, I would have to construct out my functions to act as middleware via my own design pattern? Like there aren't middleware functions like ExpressJS bodyParse I can just plug into a base 'http' nodejs server?

Comment: That's correct, you'd have to implement something similar yourself if you only have the base `http` server.